# javascript : get numbers after entry in string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a text and I want to search in text, find the word ,and then return the numbers after this word

for example :

```
this is a signal , entry : 2430 and side is short
```

I want to find entry and return 2430

how can I handle this?

Comment: use a regular-expression in a `RegExp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple regex:

```js
const input = 'this is a signal , entry : 2430 and side is short'; 

const number1 = input.match(/entry\W+(\d+)/)?.[1]; // "2430"

const number2 = input.match(/santa\W+(\d+)/)?.[1]; // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and regular expression

```js
const word = "entry";
const str = "this is a signal , entry : 2430 and side is short";

const index = str.indexOf(word);

if (index !== -1) {
  let result = str.slice(index + word.length).match(/\d+/)[0];
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: You have overcomplicated it a lot.

Comment: @RoboRobok Added another solution on the table. This is much better version of the last

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on 1 line:

```
text = 'this is a signal , entry : 2430 and side is short';
x = text.split('entry : ')[1].split(' ')[0]; // 2430
```